# Style properties on react components

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that is being repeated and the only reason its being repeated is because of the icon, color, and text.

```
import React from 'react';
const TabOne = () =>{
return (
    <div  className="irequest-tabs users">
        <span className="tabOne"><i className="fa fa-sitemap navbuttonIcon"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span className="hidden-sm hidden-xs">I want to...</span></span>
    </div>
);
}
export default TabOne
```

I wanted to see if there was a way to make those properties on the component so that my component when used would look like:

```
<Tab1 color="#fff" icon="fa fa-sitemap" text="I want too..." />
```

I've tried:

```
import React from 'react';
const TabOne = () =>{
return (
    <div style={{color: props.color}} className="irequest-tabs users">
        <span className="tabOne"><i className={props.icon}  className="navbuttonIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span className="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{props.text}</span></span>
    </div>
);
}
export default TabOne
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: I get the error "props is not defined" and "typeError"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, just pass `props` as argument to `TabOne` (I'll simplify your markup for readability).

---

```
const TabOne = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{color: props.color}}>
       <i className={props.icon}></i>
       <span>{props.text}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TabOne;
```

Remember, a functional component gets the properties passed by its parent as args to the function.